# Participants are not notified for a new call, while initiating a teams call using graph API. Is there a way to do this?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I was using graph APIs with delegated user access for creating new teams calls. Calls are created with the given attendees list but the none of the attendees are not notified even after the call is started by the organizer. The API endpoint and the request body used for this is added below.

Endpoint: POST /me/onlineMeetings

Request body: {

```
"meetingChatMode": "enabled", 

"autoAdmittedUsers": "everyone", 

"lobbyBypassSettings": { 

    "scope": "everyone", 

    "isDialInBypassEnabled": true 

}, 

"onlineMeetingPresenters": "everyone", 

"isEntryExitAnnounced": true, 

"allowAttendeeToEnableCamera": true, 

"allowAttendeeToEnableMic": true, 

"subject": "User sample meeting", 

"participants": { 

    "organizer": { 

        "identity": { 

            "user": { 

                "id": "47vdhwf891-3990-408-bdf2-5a7346873778" 

            } 

        } 

    }, 

    "attendees": [{ 

        "identity": { 

            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.identitySet" 

        }, 

        "upn": "sampleuser2@dev.com", 

        "role": "attendee" 

    }] 

}
```

}

My requirement was to notify the user as direct call or as a pop-up notification. Is there any way to do this using graph API.